# How can I jump to a frame in a stack trace according to the function name in gdb?

Tags: gdb, stack-trace

I'm debugging a stack overflow due to infinite recursion.  The program fails when the stack is 700 calls deep.

I want to jump to the frame in which the function was initially called.  However, gdb shows me the stack trace from the top of the stack about 20 entries at a time, and I wonder if I can somehow skip straight to the calling function without looking through the stack trace to find its number.

To that end, I want to be able to jump to a stack frame based on its name instead of its number.

Can this be done in gdb?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Two options:

- `up 200` will bring you up 200 frames
- If you know the initial caller of the recursive routine, you can do `f[rame] <caller-func>` - this will jump to the frame of address `caller-func`.

See [Frame Selection](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Selection.html#Selection) in the manual.

Comment: NB, as mentioned in the link, you can also use `frame function <caller-function-name>`, referring to the name of the function, instead of its frame level in the current stack-trace

Answer (score 35):

You have to use `bt` with minus.  It is similar to `bt`, but print first the outermost n frames. 

For example: 
`bt -100`

And it is likely you will see the frame that you need to inspect on the first or second screen. 
Once insecting the stack trace using `bt -100` helped me to fix a pboblem with a lot of recursive calls easily.

And then issue command 
`f <here the number of your frame you need to inspect>`

Comment: Awesome. Been looking for a way to do this. The confusing thing was always that "frame" doesn't support this notation but "bt" does.