# GDB backtrace and then jump to?

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm still on my way learning GDB. I used backtrace to find the workflow of a thread and I really wish I can jump to a certain function in the backtrace and print some variable information there. Is there a way to do that? Hope what I asked makes sense.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5688852/7431860

Comment: Thank you. Will take a look

Comment: @Jibo_Libin When (if) you find the answer to your question, please write an answer to it here. It'll help people in the future.

Comment: I did thanks. I added my own answer underneath.

Answer (score 1):

To access a certain function, just type frame # where # is the number of the function in the backtrace.

Comment: That was a good Q+A - the only thing is to accept your answer, also "marking" this question "kind of solved" (and maybe additional [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)], both will also award you a badge :-).